# Parallel simulations writing on the same file

Tags: file, parallel-processing, julia

I aim to run a 10,000 or so Julia-coded simulations in parallel (each simulation is independent of all the others) on a cluster. Each simulation has a single number to output (along with 3 columns of info about which simulation has produced this number). It therefore sounds a bit stupid to me to force each simulation to print on a separate file.

Can I safely ask all these simulations to write on the same file or might this cause a bug if two simulations happen to write on the file at the exact same time? What is the best solution?

Comment: If all these simulations are running together in one program, you could write to the file as long as you handle any contention in your code. If you have separate instances running the same code, I would advise creating a middle tier that does the actual writing and handle any resource contention there.

Comment: All simulations are running independently of each other. Among the 10,000 simulations, there are 4 sets of 2,500 simulations. Within each set the parameters are exactly the same (only the seed differ) while the parameters differ between sets. I don't know what a middle tier is and I don't think I really understand the concept of resource contention. Thanks!

Comment: For this type of case, a simulation can be executed within a function and 10,000 instances of the function can be spawned in parallel. The main program would then have the job of collecting the output from each instance of the function and writing the result to a file. The Julia documentation on [parallel computing](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/) goes into detail on how to spawn tasks in parallel and collect the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a brief example of one way in which a set of 10000 independent simulations can be set up to run in parallel in Julia, using `pmap()`:

```
@everywhere function simulate(i)
    # we compute the simulation results here. In this case we just return
    # the simulation number and a random value
    x = rand()
    return (i,x)
end

x = pmap(simulate,1:10000)
# x is the array of tuples returned from all the simulations

showall(x)
# ... or we could write x to a file or do something else with it
```

`@everywhere` is needed to ensure that the `simulate()` function is available to all processes rather than just one process. `pmap()` calls `simulate()` once for each of the values in the second parameter, in parallel, and returns an array of all the results produced by `simulate()`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize the answer would be so specific to Julia. I am still not quite sure how I can run this on the cluster I am using given that I usually `qsub` a `.pbs` file and specify the number of simulations under `#PBS -t`. Should I write `#PBS -t 1` (instead of `#PBS -t 1-10000`) and parallel the work on the `.jl` file using `pmap` as you showed me? Do you think that the system will give me access to several CPUs this way? I may have better to ask that to the guy who manages the cluster.

Comment: I've only run parallel tasks on a multicore workstation myself. According to the Julia parallel [programming documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/parallel-computing/), however, starting Julia with the "--machinefile option ... uses a passwordless ssh login to start julia worker processes (from the same path as the current host) on the specified machines." The `--machinefile` option is described [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/getting-started/?highlight=machinefile).

Comment: There are other ways to do this that are not Julia-specific, of course but, since your simulations are in Julia, it seemed like it would be easier to do it all in Julia than across several pieces of software. I'm not familiar with `qsub` so I can't help with that. Your cluster manager would be best able to help with the specifics of your cluster.